# Cant find element on office 365 page with Selenium/Python/Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, find, element

I try to find and click the e-mail button in the office 365 environment.

See image:

[image: office 365 environment]

I think its because the button is in a toolbar/subframe of the webpage. I can not find that it is in a iframe.

The problem seems to be in the following line of code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='Mail']"))).click()
```

The HTML code is looking like this:

[image]

The error i get back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\00-Python\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='Mail']"))).click()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x009A6643]
    (No symbol) [0x0093BE21]
    (No symbol) [0x0083DA9D]
    (No symbol) [0x00871342]
    (No symbol) [0x0087147B]
    (No symbol) [0x008A8DC2]
    (No symbol) [0x0088FDC4]
    (No symbol) [0x008A6B09]
    (No symbol) [0x0088FB76]
    (No symbol) [0x008649C1]
    (No symbol) [0x00865E5D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C1A142+2497106]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C485D3+2686691]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C4BB9C+2700460]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A53B10+635936]
    (No symbol) [0x00944A1F]
    (No symbol) [0x0094A418]
    (No symbol) [0x0094A505]
    (No symbol) [0x0095508B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76D900F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x772D7BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x772D7B8E+238]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `EC.visibility_of_element_located` instead. And try this XPath expression `//div[@title="Outlook"]`

Below is the complete code I used which worked perfectly fine:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url="https://www.office.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[contains(text(),"Sign in")]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,'loginfmt'))).send_keys(f"yourusername")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'idSIButton9'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,'loginfmt'))).send_keys(f"yourusername")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,'passwd'))).send_keys(f"yourpassword")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'idSIButton9'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'idBtn_Back'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Outlook"]'))).click()
```

Note: Above code is just for your reference. I think you can only use the last line of code(where you actually click on Outlook). You do not need `ExplicitWait` in all the lines of code.